# php - insert arrays on keys of other arrays. - a simple array request

Tags: php, arrays

**$extraServicos** is an array. 
I want to add a key to that array called "options" so that, on that key, I can associate another array **$extraOpcoes** . 
On this last array I want to add yet another key called "prices" and associate one last array with it: **$precosOpcao**.

How can I build such an array given the following code?

```
$extrasServicos = $servicoDao->servicosExtras($servicoVo);

foreach ($extrasServicos as $extra) {
   $servicoVo->setExtraId($extra->id);
   $extraOpcoes = $servicoDao->extrasOpcoes($servicoVo);
   $servicoVo->setPrecoMoeda('1');
   $servicoVo->setTipoServico('configoptions');    
   $precosOpcao = $servicoDao->precos($servicoVo); 
}
```

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Comment: could you give an example of how the array structure should look? as well as a small overview of what each of the functions do in your foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new key to an array in PHP, it is as simple as doing:

```
$array['new_key'] = $value;
```

In your example, it's hard to understand how exactly you want to add the keys. Since you are doing a loop, it looks like you may want an array of arrays. Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for:

```
$extrasServicos = $servicoDao->servicosExtras($servicoVo);
$extrasServicos['options'] = array();
$extrasServicos['prices'] = array();
foreach ($extrasServicos as $extra) {
   $servicoVo->setExtraId($extra->id);
   $extrasServicos['options'][] = $servicoDao->extrasOpcoes($servicoVo);
   $servicoVo->setPrecoMoeda('1');
   $servicoVo->setTipoServico('configoptions');    
   $extrasServicos['prices'][] = $servicoDao->precos($servicoVo); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you are looking for a structure such as this:

```
array (
    "options" => array(
        "prices" => array('10,95','21,99','30,31')
    )
)
```

Correct?

```
$extrasServicos = $servicoDao->servicosExtras($servicoVo);

foreach ($extrasServicos as $extra) {
   $servicoVo->setExtraId($extra->id);
   $extraOpcoes = $servicoDao->extrasOpcoes($servicoVo);
   $servicoVo->setPrecoMoeda('1');
   $servicoVo->setTipoServico('configoptions');    
   $precosOpcao = $servicoDao->precos($servicoVo);
   // Here is where you will put those into your overhead array
   $extraServicos['options'] = $extraOpcoes;
   $extraServicos['options']['price'] = $precosOpcao;
}
```

To view the structure after your run this code (to be certain it is what you are looking for) put this after the for loop (only for debug)

```
print"<pre>"; print_r($extraServicos);
```

Good luck!
Dennis M.